# angularjs ( call rest in Hibernate )

Tags: java, html, angularjs, rest

As the title my problem and how to call the services rest with the help of angularjs.
My project was built with the Dao and Dao Impl, rest and hibernate, see the code as I built it step by step.
My problem lies in the controller and the html page that do not leave the data rest.
can you view my code? to see where I was wrong? and if I'm wrong, can I correct it?

method getSkill:

```
 public List<Skill> getAllSkill() {
      List<Skill> listaSkill = new ArrayList<Skill>();
      HibernateConnection connectionHibernate = new HibernateConnection();
      // EntityManager Gestisce connessioni e transazioni,
      EntityManager manager = connectionHibernate.getEntityManagerFactory();

      // serve per gestire le operazioni di inserimento
      EntityTransaction entityTransaction = null;

      try {
         entityTransaction = manager.getTransaction(); // restituisci la transizione delle classi pojo
         entityTransaction.begin(); // inizia la transizione query
         listaSkill = manager.createQuery("select q from Skill q", Skill.class).getResultList(); // READ SKILL
         entityTransaction.commit(); // committa
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Errore -> " + e.getMessage());
         if (entityTransaction != null) {
            entityTransaction.rollback();
         }
      } finally {
         try {
            if (manager != null) {
               manager.close(); // chiudi
            }
         } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
      return listaSkill;
   }
```

rest:

```
// READ ALL SKILL
   @GET
   @Path("/getSkill")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // trasforma in json
   public Response getListSkill() {

      // Chiamo la Factory
      ISkillDao iDao = new SkillDaoImpl();

      List<Skill> result = iDao.getAllSkill();

      return Response.ok().entity(result).build();
   }
```

controller:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("read3", function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost:8900/HibernateRestDao/getSkill').then(
         function success(response) {
            alert(response.data);
         }, function myError(response) {
            consol.log("errore");
         });
});
})();
```

html:

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Id Skill</th>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>Cognome</th>
         <th>Update</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in .... "> //in here what should I put in order to recall the services rest ??? have you seen my method and the rest?
         <td>{{x.idSkill }}</td>
         <td>{{x.nome }}</td>
         <td>{{x.cognome }}</td>
         <td><a href="#!update3/{{x.idCandidato }}" class="btn btn-info">Update
               Candidato</a></td>
         <td><a href="#!delete3/{{x.idCandidato }}" class="btn btn-info">Delete
               Candidato</a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

Controller

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("read3", function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://localhost:8900/HibernateRestDao/getSkill').then(
         function success(response) {
            $scope.skillList = response.data;
            //alert(response.data);
         }, function myError(response) {
            consol.log("errore");
         });
});
})();
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Id Skill</th>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>Cognome</th>
         <th>Update</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in skillList"> //everytime controller is loaded, this variable will refresh with data
         <td>{{x.idSkill }}</td>
         <td>{{x.nome }}</td>
         <td>{{x.cognome }}</td>
         <td><a href="#!update3/{{x.idCandidato }}" class="btn btn-info">Update
               Candidato</a></td>
         <td><a href="#!delete3/{{x.idCandidato }}" class="btn btn-info">Delete
               Candidato</a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```